# Creating a 2D matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I want to Create a matrix like

```
A = [1 2 3 ;4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

I want to do it like this,

```
A = 1 + val : 1 : 3 + val ;

val = [0 3 6];
```

But I am only getting `[1 2 3]` , Not 2D matrix .

Comment: include detail code in the question, it's a bit minimalistic as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 val = [0 3 6];
 A = bsxfun(@plus,val',1:3);

 A = 
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```